# How to clear the default template for dropzonejs

Tags: javascript, dropzone.js

As it stands, dropzonejs is generating markup for every file uploaded. I do not want this nor do I want to define a custom template. As it stands, I just listen for various events and perform actions like updating HTML.

When I don't define a template, the typical default markup is generated.

```
<div class="dz-preview dz-file-preview dz-processing dz-success">
    <div class="dz-details">
        <div class="dz-filename">
            <span data-dz-name>thumbnail2.png</span>
        </div>

        <div class="dz-size" data-dz-size>
            <strong>0.1</strong> MiB
        </div>

        <img data-dz-thumbnail>
    </div>

    <div class="dz-progress">
        <span class="dz-upload" data-dz-uploadprogress style=
        "width: 100%;"></span>
    </div>

    <div class="dz-success-mark">
        <span>✔</span>
    </div>

    <div class="dz-error-mark">
        <span>✘</span>
    </div>

    <div class="dz-error-message">
        <span data-dz-errormessage></span>
    </div>
</div>
```

I don't want any markup to be generated. I've looked at the `addedfile` event and that's where it determines if a custom template is defined or generate the default markup. I don't need this.

I could easily just target `.dz-preview` and display none however I just would prefer if the HTML was never generated.

I've tried setting `previewsTemplate: ""` and that didn't work.